# Globally declared var keyword in for loop (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, for-loop

could anyone tell me why console.log(i); returns 3?

```js
var numArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  numArray.push(i);
}
console.log(numArray);
// returns [0, 1, 2]
console.log(i);
// returns 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because after `i` is `2` and pushed to `numArray`, it's incremented to `3`. However, this fails to meet the condition that `i < 3`, so the loop is exited, however `i` remains as `3` which is why you see it in `console.log`. The key point to understand is that in JavaScript loops, the incrementer code `i++` is applied at the end of each iteration, but the conditional check is applied at the start of each iteration, which is why this occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I still am not sure why the same rule applies to `console.log(numArray);`. How come the end of the array returns "2" not "3" ? Sorry I'm still a beginner.

Comment: Because the `numArray` pushing only happens after the conditional - so only when `I` is less than 3 will the `push` run.